# shared_preferences _CastError

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

The supplied example works

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: Text('Increment Counter'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

, but say I want to load data before runApp. Just move _incrementCounter() like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
 _incrementCounter(); 
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: Text('Increment Counter'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

but now I get an "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)".

It would be real nice to have a init() before runApp, but it seems that at least shared_preferences somehow relies of something going on in runApp.

If not before runApp, then where should initialization using shared_preferences be put?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` inside the main function:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // Add this

 await _incrementCounter(); // Also, add await here since the function is async

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: Text('Increment Counter'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

The thing is, SharedPreferences uses a native platform code to initialize the storage. Flutter platform channels are used for this communication, so you need to ensure that Flutter engine binding is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `initState()` in StatefulWidget. Because it's the first function run when starting a StatefullWidget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // Get shared_preferences in here
    print('Async done');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('object');
    print('object2');
    print('object3');
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

You can visit the website to understand the life cycle of StatefullWidget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html